# SMTP Attachement only a few bytes sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient, mailmessage

I'm trying to attach a image to my email. 
I'm doing it this way.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

MailMessage mailDSS = new MailMessage();

//Setting From , To and CC
mailDSS.From = new MailAddress(billModel.Email, "from: " + billModel.Email);
mailDSS.To.Add(new MailAddress("username@email.com"));

mailDSS.Subject = "This is my subject";
mailDSS.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(billModel.UploadedBill.Path + billModel.UploadedBill.Filename));
mailDSS.Attachments.Add(aAttachment);

mailDSS.Body = "This is the content :" + billModel.Name;
smtpClient.Send(mailDSS);
```

And it works but when I try to change it to a memory stream it doesn't work.
this is what I'm trying to make work:

```
 mailDSS.From = new MailAddress(billModel.Email, "from: " + billModel.Email);
 mailDSS.To.Add(new MailAddress("username@email.com"));

 mailDSS.Subject = "This is my subject";

 billModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
 Attachment aAttachment = new Attachment(billModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream, billModel.UploadedBill.Filename);
 aAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = billModel.UploadedBill.Filename;


 mailDSS.Attachments.Add(aAttachment);

 mailDSS.Body = "This is the content :" + billModel.Name;
 smtpClient.Send(mailDSS);
```

what am I doing wrong ? the only difference between the two is one is a reference to a file on the disk where the other is a reference to a file from a stream =?

BillModel is just a domain model class made serializable.

```
public class BillModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CivilRegistrationNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public int RegNo { get; set; }
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string PaymentGuarentee { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public MemoryFileStream UploadedBill { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:
There are no error messages the email is sent fine the attachment however is only 227bytes on arrival where the attachments should had been 20 kilobytes. So I do not know how I can describe my problem anymore clear. My debugging amounts to trying different approaches some didn't work some is a small variation of the above-mentioned. All have the same issue with corrupting the file.

If there is something specific you need me to show in order to help me I will be happy to provide but atm I do not see what else I can show? It simply doesn't work as I intended.

Comment: What is the error/problem you are seeing?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't give us much of a clue as to what the issue is. Please describe your problem in detail, and describe the debugging work you've done so far.

Comment: Wait... you create the attachment giving it the stream `Attachment aAttachment = new Attachment(billModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream` but then you copy it to the attachment stream? `billModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream.CopyTo(aAttachment.ContentStream)` that's gotta be wrong. Get rid of the CopyTo and try again.

Comment: @awh112 no error message. Problem is as described only a few bytes send with the email. Instead of the 20kb it should have been.

Comment: @aDyson it is kind of difficult describ more than I already did. It works but instead of a 20kb file sent it is a corrupt 227byte file that arrives in my inbox.

Comment: @will you are right that part is no good it was an attempt to see if I could force the file to be sent but alas it didn't work I just forgot to remove it again. Have the same issue with or without that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.

the problem was not in what I showed. but where I was running this from.

in my testmethod I did this

```
   using (System.IO.Stream fileData = System.IO.File.OpenRead(TestFilenamePath))
        {
            string filenamePath = aBillModel.UploadedBill.Path + filename;

            using (System.IO.FileStream newFileData = System.IO.File.Create(filenamePath))
            {
                fileData.Position = 0;
                fileData.CopyTo(newFileData);
            }

            fileData.CopyTo(aBillModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream);

            //Perform Action to be tested
            bool emailSendt = EmailSender.Send(aBillModel);

            //Test Result of Action
            Assert.That(emailSendt, Is.True);
        }
```

And apparently I couldn't both write the data to a location on the disk and at the same time send it with an email. 
So I did this instead.

```
   using (System.IO.Stream fileData = System.IO.File.OpenRead(TestFilenamePath))
        {
            string filenamePath = aBillModel.UploadedBill.Path + filename;

            using (System.IO.FileStream newFileData = System.IO.File.Create(filenamePath))
            {
                fileData.Position = 0;
                fileData.CopyTo(newFileData);
            }
        }
        using (System.IO.Stream fileData = System.IO.File.OpenRead(TestFilenamePath))
        {
            fileData.CopyTo(aBillModel.UploadedBill.FileDataStream);

            //Perform Action to be tested
            bool emailSendt = EmailSender.Send(aBillModel);

            //Test Result of Action
            Assert.That(emailSendt, Is.True);
        }
```

and it solved my problem of receiving a corrupt file of only a few bytes in size instead of getting the file of 20Kb in size.